# Wifi adapter is not working in Ubuntu 16.04 but it works fine in Ubuntu 16.04 live CD

Tags: 16.04, wireless, mediatek

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 I bought 802.11N wifi adapter.

`lsusb` returns

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

My wifi adapter is not working in my PC.
It's working on Ubuntu 16.04 live cd.

What may be the problem in my system ?

Any one please help me

Comment: Check for the additional drivers in the `software and updates` settings.

Comment: Have you tried doing "apt update" and then trying to connect it?

Comment: I tried "apt update" and then tried to reconnect.  No my wifi adapter is not working.

Comment: Try loading the driver to see if there are any errors or clues: `sudo modprobe mt7601u`

Comment: Hi thanks for your comments.  I re-installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my system now wifi adapter is working.